# How IDoc are stored/used in SAP

Tags: idoc

I am struggling to understand how IDoc are used in SAP. What an IDoc is I understand but I have a few questions about how this IDoc are used by SAP (can't find such details on sap blog):

1. In SAP database all the tables are stored in IDocs? For example, if I create table employees with 4 records, the entire table will be stored in the body of an IDoc?
2. Is possible to make a query in the database and to receive the information as an IDoc?
3. In connection with the above question. In SAP are predefined types of IDocs ([video to create an IDoc in SAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=5&v=jNeEV7VJulk))? Or we can create various types of IDocs (for example I create an IDoc, in its body I put some text and send it to an SAP system)?
4. An IDoc has many segments, how should I decide which of them should I use? (like the guy from above video)

PS: I am new with SAP and all these things are new for me.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still looking for clarification regarding IDocs, I recommend the SAP Learning Hub ebook on ALE (application link enabling). It offers a technical and conceptual summary of IDoc technology and its use in SAP.

To answer a few of your questions, yes, there are predefined IDoc types. Together, the basic type and message type characterise the structure and data to be sent in the IDoc.

The IDoc itself consists of:

1. Control Record: this is the metadata, where information concerning
   the IDoc type and details of sending and receiving systems are
   stored.
2. Data Records: this is where the information (stored in segments)
   that you are sending can be found.
3. Status Records: contains information concerning whether the IDoc
   transfer was successful. If the IDoc fails, you can investigate the
   potential reason by looking at the status codes here.

The segments that you use will be defined by the configuration and business requirements of the SAP system you are working in. You can append the segments and create customer defined types, but, as there are so many predefined IDocs, there will likely already exist something you can use.

IDocs are intended to be used in integration scenarios. They can be used to send data out of an SAP system or to receive data into an SAP system. IDocs are designed for data exchange between, rather than within, a system. They can be sent to other SAP systems or to non SAP systems, depending on business requirements. This is their main purpose in SAP.

If you are interested in the process of configuring an ALE scenario for a specific business process, this blog post provides a thorough example:

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/ale-distribution-of-cost-center-and-gl-account-master-data-across-sap-systems-through-idocs/

Answer (score 1):

> In SAP database all the tables are stored in IDocs? For example, if I
>   create table employees with 4 records, the entire table will be stored
>   in the body of an Idoc?

No tables are tables.  Idocs are stored in their own tables. IDOCs represent data to is be posted or was sent depending on the direction .

> Is possible to make a query in the database and to receive the
>   information as an IDoc?

Yes you can read the IDOC header and segments.
If you dont know how IDOCs are stored, (headers, segments, status records) then doing so is not a great idea. Research IDOC storage first. 
Use a Function might be a better idea ;)

> In connection with the above question. In SAP are predefined types of
>   Idocs(create an IDoc in SAP)?

Yes SAP supplies many standard IDOCS.

> Or we can create various types of IDocs(for example I create an IDoc,
>   in his body, I put some text and send it to an SAP system)?

You can create you own IDOCs, you can add segments to existing IDOCs.
There is documentation on how to do this.

> An IDoc has many segments, how should I decide which of them should I
>   use? (like the guy from above video)

It has the data you need.

Ask the person planning to use IDOCs for help.
Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your questions, I am afraid that you might not have understood what an IDoc is. Maybe you will find this little crash course useful for getting an overview:

https://www.guru99.com/all-about-idocdefinition-architecture-implementation.html

Comment: Still is not all clear but your link is very useful. Thanks.